# Pegar valores digitados em inputs dentro de datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json, jquery-datatables

Eu possuo em um HTML uma *datatable* e em cada linha eu tenho 3 *inputs* (text, datepicker e select) e um botão, que vai mandar pro PHP, para registrar o que foi digitado ou selecionado nos *inputs* daquela linha. O que eu estou tentando fazer é pegar as informações da linha em que eu apertar o botão. O que pensei em fazer é serializar a tabela e transformar em um *array* usando JQuery; o problema é que ele trás as informações de todas as linhas da *datatable*, mas o que eu preciso é apenas da linha que eu aperta o botão.

Não posso pegar os valores por *id* dos *inputs* pois a *datatable* é preenchida automaticamente pelo PHP.

Segue código:

```
var table = $('#tableList').DataTable();
$("#tableList").on("click", ".btnReceived", function() {
    var data = JSON.stringify(table.$('input, select').serializeArray());
    console.log(data);
});
```

Segue HTML onde é criado o botão:

```
<a class='btn btn-orange btn-xs btnReceived' href='#' title='Confirmar Recebimento'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-saved'></span><a/>
```

Comment: Os outros estao vindo vazios?

Comment: Estão. Se o datatable tiver mil linhas e eu preenchi apenas 1, ele trás em um json mil linhas, com 999 vazios e 1 com o que preenchi.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, voce pode verificar os que estiverem vazio e usar um `splice` para retira-los, assim so vai manter os que foram digitados

Comment: Acredito que verificar não seria um caminho viável, se for pensar no ponto de vista do meu usuário, ele vai primeiro preencher os inputs para depois ir clicando nos botões, isso ja acabaria com minha verificação... Acredito que se tivesse uma forma de pegar apenas as informações da linha do botão que eu clicar, seria melhor.

Comment: Vocé não entendeu, quando eu digo verificar, digo voce mesmo, para o usuario nao fara diferença, pois o codigo mesmo faria tudo isso.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de como poderia fazer, verificando e armazenando apenas os campos que tiverem informação.

```js
document.getElementById('enviar').onclick = function(){
  let elemento = document.getElementsByClassName('a')
  
  let arr = []

  for(let i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++){
    if(elemento[i].value == ''){
      
    }else{
      arr.push({
        'valor': elemento[i].value
      })
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="a">
  <input type="text" class="a">
  <input type="text" class="a">
  
  <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Vou fazer alguns testes aqui dessa forma e dou um retorno aqui. Grato!

Comment: E como eu poderia diferenciar as informações que estão no array (arr) ? Tipo, de qual linha é cada informação.

Comment: voce usaria essa infomação para o que?

Comment: Vou usar para dar update em uma tabela do banco de dados. A primeira coluna do datatable é um id, se eu conseguisse diferenciar por esse id pelo menos, já serviria.

Comment: Eu nao consegui entender muito bem, mas voce poderia passar esse ID pelo botao que clica, nao? se em cada tem um botao, pode atribuir um attr a esse botao e recuperar esse id para fazer o update

Comment: Os botões existem em todas as linhas, também foram criados dinamicamente, então eles não possuem id ou name especifico e tal, mesmo assim eu teria como fazer isso que você disse?

Comment: Sim, teria sim, me diz uma coisa, cada linha é um ID correto? ou não?

Comment: Sim, em cada linha existe um id, na primeira coluna do datatable.

Comment: Então, qual o codigo que usa para adicionar o botao?, poderia editar sua pergunta adicionando ele?